# SDL & Windows 8 Metro WinRT

Tags: directx, sdl

I am just beginning to dip my tow into game programming and have been reading up on SDL, SFML, OpenGL, XNA, MonoGame and of course DirectX. (Needless to say there are a lot of choices out there)

As much as I like SFMLs syntax I have chosen to read up and start with SDL as it is pretty ubiquitous and available on every platform (Windows, Linux, Mac) and also available on portable devices (Android, iOS) with the current exception of WinPhone 7

After that pre-amble here is my question.

I notice that the docs say that for the windows platform the SDL API calls through to DirectX for higher perf. ( http://www.libsdl.org/intro.en/whatplatforms.html )

Microsoft have said that for Metro Game Apps you can only use DirectX (which means no XNA, no OpenGL, no SFML, etc, etc)

My question is: If SDL just wraps DirectX calls will I (we) be able to use SDL to bring games to the new Metro WinRT environment and Windows 8 marketplace?

This would be great if possible. Additionally as WinPhone 8 is supposedly built on Win8 then this could mean SDL would be available on the win phone in the future too.

Thanks for your time in responding to this question and I look forward to hearing your response.

EDIT:

Based on DeadMG's answer I have installed Visual Studio 11 (beta) in Windows 8 Consumer Preview (CP) and went file->New to check project types. The project types:

"Blank Application", "Direct2D Application" and "Direct3D Application"

look of interest. I have selected "Direct2D App" but SDL generates its own window when you call: SDL_INIT

Is it possible to link/setup the SDL window to point to the Direct2D surface in the this project?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way that Microsoft could possibly tell the difference between you calling DX directly, and calling DX through a wrapper or third party library, so it's utterly irrelevant whether you use SDL or SFML or write your own.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You mention SFML here but as far as I understand SFML is a wrapper for OpenGL only. Is this correct?? All the documentation seem to point to this.  If it is OpenGL as I believe then using it for Metro/WinRT development is a dead end. Microsoft will never support OpenGL for Metro dev when they are pushing DirectX as hard as they are. They have even stopped C# XNA from targeting Metro which is their own property.

Comment: Okay, I just installed Visual Studio 11 (beta) in Windows 8 Consumer Preview (CP) and went file->New to check project types. The project types "Blank Application", "Direct2D Application" and "Direct3D Application" look of interest. I have selected "Direct2D App" but SDL generates its own window! Is it possible to link/setup the SDL window to point to the Direct2D surface in the this project?

Comment: @Adrian: This is not a forum. It's a Q&A site. If you have a new question (which this is), you ask it with the "Ask Question" button, not by making a comment.